# Unexpected .data memory address in MIPS, can't print proper asciiz character

Tags: arrays, assembly, ascii, mips, memory-address

I'm trying to print an array with its characters separated by a comma, for example: {1, 2, 3...} To achieve this I declared a variable `separator: .asciiz ", "` in my .data section of the code. However, I have some other variables in the .data section and I believe they're creating an unexpected result in the addresses of themselves.

```
.data
    numero: .word 0 
    prompt: .ascii "Digite el valor de n: "
    incorrecto: .ascii "Digite el valor de n: "
    


    lista_numerador: .space 40
    separator: .asciiz ", "
    espacio1: .space 40
    lista_denominador: .space 40
.text

    main:
        jal getNumber
        lw $s0, numero              
        addi $a0, $v0, 0            

        jal numerador
        jal denominador
        jal print_list

        addi $v0, $0, 10
        syscall

    print_list:
        la $s1, lista_numerador
        addi $t0, $0, 0
        addi $s0, $a0, 0    #s0 = 4
        mul $s1, $a0, $a0
        

        print_loop:
            slt $t3, $t0, $s1       # t3 = 1 if i < 4*4
            beq $t3, $0, end_print

            sll $t1, $t0, 2         # i*4
            add $t2, $a1, $t1       # A + i*4
            
            lw $a0, ($t2)           
            addi $v0, $0, 1
            syscall

            la $a0, separator
            addi $v0, $0, 4
            syscall

            addi $t0, $t0, 1
            j print_loop
            
        end_print:
            jr $ra
```

I've seen that depending on whether I put the "separator" line before, after or in the middle of the lines of the arrays, everything changes (I had a bug where one of the arrays address' ended in 7, not a multiple of 4). With this current code my output in MARS is this:

[image: With this current code my output in MARS is this:]

Obviously the expected result is {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...} but I'm getting those weird boxes.

I think the cause of the problem is the address $a0 gets in the line `la $a0, separator`, MARS says its value is 0x10010058 but I don't know what should be the correct, expected value.

Any hindsight is much appreciated. Thanks!

If I don't create the memory space for lista_denominador it prints properly.

Comment: You should check the separator, verify its string value in memory at the start of the program, so you know how it should look, then again when it is used.  Suspect your program is overwriting that string.

Comment: The parameter to `.space` is in units of *bytes* - you appear to be storing *words* in these arrays, so your 40 bytes only gives you room for 10 words of data.  And your example output shows 16 data items...

Comment: So increasing the size of the arrays to, for example, 1000 bytes should be okay? @jasonharper

Comment: Any idea how to do this? On MARS I only know how to look at the value in the middle of the simulation. I can't specifically see what happens on the .data lines @ErikEidt

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the MARS simulator, it is stopped before the execution of the first machine code instruction (you have to tell it to run or single step) but you can poke around memory and the registers to see the initial state of the loaded binary program.

This gives you the opportunity to inspect the binary, here, your data in memory, which has been brought about by the `.data` section declarations in your assembly.  Analogous to the "Text Segment" window, which holds the assembled machine code instructions and that we use for single step debugging, there is a "Data Segment" window you can use to see your data.

Further, there is also a "Labels" window that shows label names and their final addresses when the program has been loaded into memory.

So, you can refer to the "Labels" window to find the address of your string declared as `separator: .asciiz ", "` — just look up the address associated with `separator`.

Then adjust the "Data Segment" window to show the addresses around that memory location.  Unlike the "Text Segment" where you can use the mouse to scroll up and down, in the "Data Segment" there are instead two inconvenient arrows to move the view of memory locations shown "Data Segment" window.

You can only move the window a fixed amount so you can generally only get close to seeing what you want and you'll have to count over the columns to find your data; also inconvenient but also a logical thing, so you can find the exact address of interest.  Further, the memory is displayed by default in words not in ascii, but there is a toggle in the Data Segment window for "ASCII".

A comma followed by a space may be somewhat hard to find, so you can temporarily make that declaration to be a much larger and more identifiable string, so you can see it with less mental effort to find the right position.

The larger string will be equally trashed by your program's array indexing out of bounds.  An approach is to look to see when the first characters of your string are wiped out.  It will happen on one single instruction and is observable during single step.

A correct program will not go out of bounds of arrays (in particular the one that precedes the overwritten string).  In any case the exact point (one instruction) when this happens can be observed in the debugger, and you should look at the code there to see whether there's a bug in the algorithm accidentally proceeding past the end of the array for some reason, or the array and loop iteration count are mismatched, as in the array is too small for the data set you're using, as others have mentioned.  Remember that words, being 32 bits wide, each occupy 4 memory locations, and hence also 4 memory addresses.